# White screen in InappWebView with QGIS in option Google maps (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I used the QGIS for show all the options in the maps, but when I try to show google satellite maps it shows me a blank screen.

[My code of InappWebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr0jW.png)

[View of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GD5W.png)
[View of the browser "Chrome"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWFAk.jpg)

I try change the version and use other package "flutter_webview_plugin" but in this package cannot be take screenshot.